# spark-cassandra-connect python deleteFromCassandra method

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i'm using Spark, Cassandra, Spark-Cassandra-Connector on Databricks Notebook, according to their website,  we can use 'deleteFromCassandra' to delete rows: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md, https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-349
and here is my python script:

```
def read_table(tableName,kespace, columns):
  dfData = (spark
        .read
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(table = tableName, keyspace = kespace)
        .load()
        .select(*columns))
  return dfData 

emails='abc@test.com'.split(",")
df = read_table(my_table, my_keyspace,"*").where(col("email").isin(emails))
df.rdd.deleteFromCassandra(my_keyspace, my_table)
```

and it failed:

```
AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'deleteFromCassandra'
```

noticed all the exampled they provided is in Scala, does it mean that function 'deleteFromCassandra' is not available in Python?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with stock Spark Cassandra Connector, as the Python bindings support only data frames. But it should be possible with p[yspark-cassandra](https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra), that is also available on [Spark Packages site](https://spark-packages.org/package/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra) as `--packages anguenot:pyspark-cassandra:2.4.0`. Something like this:

```py
dataFrame.rdd().deleteFromCassandra(keyspace, table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves -

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

Comment: question is about Python, not Scala!